# How can fake URL on hover and right-click (copy link localtion) but not on the click?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

My [website](http://www.visualise.ca/) is running Wordpress and I use fancybox to nicely load images and image galleries. The cleaned version of my Wordpress loop output ends up looking like this:

```
<article>
 <a href="image1.jpg" id="1460" rel="fancybox-1460"><img src="image1-thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
 <div class="nodisplay">
 <a href="image2.jpg" rel="fancybox-1460">&nbsp;</a>
 <a href="image3.jpg" rel="fancybox-1460">&nbsp;</a>
 <a href="image4.jpg" rel="fancybox-1460">&nbsp;</a>
 </div>
</article>
```

When the user click on the image1 link, the images gallery is launched via fancybox and this is great. I can also provide a direct url to this gallery:

```
http://www.visualise.ca/#1460
```

My problem is that when people will visit my website, they will sometimes right click on the thumnails in order to copy the link of the gallery and they will end up giving the following to others:

```
http://www.visualise.ca/image1.jpg
```

instead of:

```
http://www.visualise.ca/#1460
```

So I would like to fake the url in order to make sure people give the right one to others (url with hash). I have to make sure the url to image1.jpg is changed to [http://www.visualise.ca/#1460][7] on hover and right-click but not on the click itself.

I also think the javascript or jQuery code has to be done inside the loop so I can use the following:

```
<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/#<?php the_ID(); ?>
```

to obtain this from Wordpress:

```
http://www.visualise.ca/#1460
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak your fancybox script to use image as a background instead and link it your desired link.

something like this..

```
<a href="http://www.visualise.ca/#1460" id="1460" style="background: url('image1-thumbnail.jpg');"></a>
```

This way the "Copy Image Location" would not be displayed, and the "Copy Link Location" will copy the URL that you want.

Alternatively

1. You can use javascript to track
   right clicks that are made, hide the
   context menu and copy the location
   into the clipboard and intimate the
   user about it. (less user friendly)
2. The last option is provide a button
   like "Copy Image URL" which on
   clicked will copy the URL to
   clipboard.

Comment: I don't understand how I can tweak fancybox to load the background image. And the loaded image has to be the large one not the thumbnail.